# execute when div reaches position

Tags: jquery

I have a function that moves a box from right to left of a page on click. When the div starts to exit the window and thus has a negative position based on my function, I would like to fire an event. I however get no response when the div passes the edge of the left side of the screen. Anyone have any ideas?

I know the position `($('#container').position().left/$(document).width())*100)` is defined and if I changed <0 to >0 when the page is initially loaded, the alert will fire.

```
<script>
$("#play").live('click', function() {
  $("#container").animate({"left": "-=100%"}, 25000);
});
if (($('#container').position().left/$(document).width())*100<0){
    alert('test');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `step` option to [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate):

> `step`: A function to be called after each step of the animation.

Something like this:

```
$("#container").animate({"left": "-=100%"}, {
    duration: 25000,
    step: function() {
        if(($('#container').position().left / $(document).width())*100 < 0) {
            alert('test');
        }
    }
});
```

That will get you your `alert` as soon as your position test is true. The animation may keep going after the `#container` is off the screen of course.

Comment: Ok I just discovered an issue. Instead of doing the alert I am actually doing   $('#preview_container').remove();. As soon as the element is removed I get unlimited errors in firebug saying $('#container').position().left is null. Have any ideas mu?

Comment: @Scarface: You could `var pos = $('#container').position();` and then `if(pos && pos.left / ....)`. Just unwrap the `if` a little bit so that you can slip a `null` check in.

Comment: Thanks again buddy, you have been very helpful and I appreciate your time.